# AWS to host assets and client side static code at central repository which should be accessible from node to upload files to central location

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am using AWS to run my application based on MEAN stack. I am using load balancer with three instances of Node application servers and three instances of mongo database server on cluster. My application has feature to upload file contents to server, mainly images, audios, vidoes etc. I want following

1. I want to create one central content repository which should be accessible from all of my three node application servers so that my node code should be able to upload files to central content repository.
2. I want to one URL to access this central content repository which can be used on user interface to load assets and display it
3. I also want to re-purpose this same central repository to host all of my client side javascript, css, images and would like my index.html to refer client side assets from central repository URL

I was looking into options in AWS however go confused. Not able to understand what is best and easy approach. Following is server architecture for reference.
[image: Server Architecture using AWS]

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out to use EC2 to solve this problem, so I changed my implementation approach, rather than hosting files on file system, I am using the MongoDB GridFS to store files. It helped to make it available for each nodejs hosts.